# What is a "Gutenberg mind"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across this phrase in yet another [novel-is-dead kind of article](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/may/02/will-self-novel-dead-literary-fiction), where the author refers to literary critics as the "possessors of Gutenberg minds". I was wondering if anyone else has heard this phrase, and what it may mean?

The author references Marshall McLuhan as its source, so it seems to come from that man's philosophy, which deals with the effects of mass media and communications in the 50's and 60's.

Comment: So put it together, Gutenberg invented the movable type printing press (mass media) the author is talking about the effects of mass media.  A Gutenberg mind is either a mind like Gutenberg's or a mind that is the product of mass media- one that isn't capable of dealing with a piece of writing as long as a novel.  Which is more likely in context?

Comment: Is this actually about English?  Wouldn’t saying “the mind of (a) Gutenberg” in any other language require the same interpretation of the literary reference?

Comment: In The Gutenberg Galaxy, [McLuhan studies the emergence of what he calls Gutenberg Man, the subject produced by the change of consciousness wrought by the advent of the printed book.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gutenberg_Galaxy). This question is about *culture/philosophy*, not English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cultural references (the invention of the printing press, not US culture in the 50s & 60s) that aren't peculiar to English.